# Regarding jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 pages say page1 and page2. In page1 I have a variable say x=20 (but this value changes dynamically ) and I have included this page1 in page2 by using some include syntax. Now i have to get that 'x' variable in my page2 using jquery and display on the webpage or store in some other variable.
Any ideas please help. . .
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are these pages loading, via ajax or by changing the whole address?

Comment: How do you include pages? Loading via Ajax, including at the server side with e.g. PHP? You have to provide more information.

Comment: I have included page using <dsp:include> syntax

Comment: is there any other way to access the variable other than using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can't include one page in another page. The result of the include is a single page that contains the code from the two files.

As it's a single page, you can just use the variable directly.

Comment: i have used <dsp:include> tag

Comment: @Unknown: Yes, that is a server side tag that includes the code from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access x in page2 using `window.parent.x`. This might help but I'm not sure. This should work with a frame, not sure what you mean with "some include syntax".

Regards